# Django: how do I loop through a second list within a paginated list?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a basic post application where each post can have many children, and each post can have a parent. I am implementing the model something like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)    
    parent = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The integer field will reference the ID of another Post, and any post with a parent of 0 will have no parents.

In the main template, I am having a problem reliably accessing the children of a parent post. I am looping through the main set of parent posts using a Paginator, and within each post I need to loop through the list of child posts.

Setting a new attribute for each post to contain the list of children works at times, but sometimes the children won't show at all when refreshing the browser repeatedly. Here is the view:

```
def home(request):
    parent_posts = Post.objects.filter(parent__exact=0)
    child_posts = [] # also try to access a second list from the template
    for post in parent_posts:
        children = Post.objects.filter(parent__exact=post.id)
        child_posts.append(children)
        post.children = children # this seems to work sometimes

    paginator = Paginator(parent_posts, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        post_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        post_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        post_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'post_list': post_list,
        'child_posts': child_posts,
    }

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do in the template:

```
<h2>Posts</h2>
{% for post in post_list %}
    {{ post.title }} by {{ post.author }}
    {% for child in post.children %}
        Child post: {{ child.title }} by {{ child.author }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

As I mentioned, this method seems to work, but sometimes when refreshing the page no child posts will show up at all. Why is that? Is setting a new attribute for each Post in the view even supposed to work?

I have also tinkered around with looping through the second list, but haven't gotten anything to work:

```
<h2>Posts</h2>
{% for post in post_list %}
    {{ post.title }} by {{ post.author }}
    {% for child in child_posts.forloop.parentloop.counter0 %}
        Child post: {{ child.title }} by {{ child.author }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have also thought about grouping the two lists of parents and children into a list of tuples in the view, but I would have no idea how to do that with the pagination.

I'm not sure if this is a simple solution or will require a complete rework, but I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ForeignKey to "self" like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)    
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

then, on your views send a nested list:

```
 parent_posts = Post.objects.filter(parent=None)
    posts = []
    for p in parent_posts:
        children = Post.objects.filter(parent=p)
        posts.append([p, children])
```

Then, on your template you should have no problem looping:

```
<h2>Posts</h2>
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.0.title }} by {{ post.0.author }}
    {% for child in post.1 %}
        Child post: {{ child.title }} by {{ child.author }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Haven't tested it, but I guess it will work. Let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: Wouldn't this work the same without changing the model? I tried doing this without changing the model, but I think I still run into the same problem using the paginator while trying to also group the children with the parents.

Comment: I would need to see your new code. And maybe you want to try endless paginator: http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/start.html